# CCID protocol command types

Tags: usb, smartcard, javacard, apdu, pcsc

based on the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCID_(protocol)):

According to the CCID specification by the USB standards work group, a CCID exchanges information through a host computer over USB by using a CCID message that consists of a 10-byte header followed by message-specific data.[2] The standard defines fourteen commands that the host computer can use to send data and status and control information in messages. Every command requires at least one response message from the CCID.

I'm seeking detailed information about this hardware specification of the CCID protocol such as mentioned 14 commands,their equivalent APDU and etc.

Comment: I guess the CCID specification, itself is what you want. You can download it [here](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/DWG_Smart-Card_CCID_Rev110.pdf). I checked your question in the NXP forum. Did you choose your target card? PCSC Specifications have also useful information for you.(Specially part 3 or 4). But if you let us know your target card, it will be more probable to receive practical answers.

Comment: Since this as the same level of communication as protocol and parameter selection for ISO 7816-3 interface or collision handling for contactless cards, I would be more than surprised to find APDUs here. Establishing connection has to be done on driver/protocol level.

Answer (score 2):

The official CCID specification: [Link](https://www.usb.org/document-library/smart-card-ccid-version-11)

Also helpful document (not public available): ISO 7816-3

Comment: Can I have your mail address please?